# build a second constructor which sets the radius to a particular value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
    private:
        double radius;
    public:
        Circle():radius(0){}
        void setRadius(double rad);
        double getRadius();
        double getArea(){return radius*radius*3.1415;}
        double getCircumference();
        double getDiameter();
        void scale(double factor);
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just add:
Circle(double radius) : radius(radius) {}

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
    double radius;
    public:
        Circle():radius(0){}
        Circle(double value): radius(value){}
        void setRadius(double rad);
        double getRadius();
        double getArea(){return radius*radius*3.1415;}
        double getCircumference();
        double getDiameter();
        void scale(double factor);
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```